# Crawling Public website using SharePoint online 2013

Tags: search, sharepoint-online, crawling, office-365

Is it possible to crawl any public website (e.g. www.xyz.com) using online version of SharePoint 2013 (Office 365 enterprise Preview)?

If it is possible could some please guide me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, you don't have access to the service application itself which would allow you to create such a (previously named) scope.